# Call another thread function then return value

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have two thread im trying to call a function on my main thread which works fine. As seen below.

```
  this.Invoke(new Action(() => myFunction()));
```

But when i try to return a value to a variable. I cant figure out how to get the return value of this function.

This doesn't work but is what i want to achieve. 
The value variable should have the return value of my function in a perfect world.

```
   string value = this.Invoke(new Action(() => myFunction()));
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What's the return of your invoke method? `this.Invoke`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but capturing result of `myFunction` into local variable inside the delgate will get work done:

```
string value;
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { value= myFunction();} ));
```

Or as TyCobb pointed out something like following should work as [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns result of a function:

```
string value = (string)this.Invoke(myFunction);
```

Comment: I think you can also use `Func<T>` instead of `Action` which would return the actual value since `Invoke` does return an `object`. I think...

Comment: The second example is terrible. If the code is already running on the UI thread then this call is synchronous - and not on another thread like the OP wanted. If the code is not on the UI thread then it pushes the potentially long-running task to the UI thread - which sounds like the exact opposite thing that the OP wants.

Comment: @Enigmativity I guess I'm missing something - first and second sample are essentially the same from point of view when/what runs, so while it quite possible wrong solution I don't see why you singling out the second one.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - You're right, they're both the same. I shouldn't have singled out the second one. However, I've taken a closer look at the question and the OP is asking to do what you've suggested. I don't think what he's doing is right, but you have answered his question.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to do what you want is to use tasks. In an `async` function you can await the value using tasks like this:

```
string value = await Task.Run(myFunction);
```

Or, if you like, like this:

```
string value = await Task.Run(() => myFunction());
```

I prefer using Microsoft's reactive framework (Nuget "Rx-Main"), like this:

```
Observable.Start(myFunction).Subscribe(value =>
{
    /* do something with `value` */
});
```

The reactive framework has so many more operators that the TPL you can do so much more succinctly with it.

Just to give you a small flavour, here's an example query to asynchronously download a series of webpages that contain a particular string:

```
var query =
    from url in urls.ToObservable()
    from content in Observable.Using(
        () => new WebClient(),
        wc => Observable.Start(() => wc.DownloadString(url)))
    where content.Contains("<div class=\"foo\" />")
    select new
    {
        url,
        content,
    };
```